# Anyone else get this error "Error: invalid option: --with-passenger"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Can not get NGINX to install with passenger

Following the steps you are supposed to...
brew install passenger

Then you run the following command...
brew install nginx --with-passenger

But I get:
Error: invalid option: --with-passenger

Could not find any resources about this online, so asking here.

$ brew install nginx --with-passenger
Usage: brew install [options] formula

Install formula.

formula is usually the name of the formula to install, but it can be specified
in several different ways.

```
-d, --debug                      If brewing fails, open an interactive
                                 debugging session with access to IRB or a
                                 shell inside the temporary build directory
    --env                        If std is passed, use the standard build
                                 environment instead of superenv.If super
                                 is passed, use superenv even if the formula
                                 specifies the standard build environment.
    --ignore-dependencies        Skip installing any dependencies of any
                                 kind. If they are not already present, the
                                 formula will probably fail to install.
    --only-dependencies          Install the dependencies with specified
                                 options but do not install the specified
                                 formula.
    --cc                         Attempt to compile using provided
                                 compiler. compiler should be the name
                                 of the compiler's executable, for instance
                                 gcc-7 for GCC 7. In order to use LLVM's
                                 clang, use llvm_clang. To specify the
                                 Apple-provided clang, use clang. This
                                 parameter will only accept compilers that
                                 are provided by Homebrew or bundled with
                                 macOS. Please do not file issues if you
                                 encounter errors while using this flag.
-s, --build-from-source          Compile the specified formula from source
                                 even if a bottle is provided. Dependencies
                                 will still be installed from bottles if
                                 they are available.
    --force-bottle               Install from a bottle if it exists for the
                                 current or newest version of macOS, even if
                                 it would not normally be used for
                                 installation.
    --include-test               Install testing dependencies required to
                                 run brew test.
    --devel                      If formula defines it, install the
                                 development version.
    --HEAD                       If formula defines it, install the HEAD
                                 version, aka. master, trunk, unstable.
    --fetch-HEAD                 Fetch the upstream repository to detect if
                                 the HEAD installation of the formula is
                                 outdated. Otherwise, the repository's HEAD
                                 will be checked for updates when a new
                                 stable or development version has been
                                 released.
    --keep-tmp                   Don't delete the temporary files created
                                 during installation.
    --build-bottle               Prepare the formula for eventual bottling
                                 during installation.
-f, --force                      Install without checking for previously
                                 installed keg-only or non-migrated
                                 versions.
-v, --verbose                    Print the verification and postinstall
                                 steps.
    --display-times              Print install times for each formula at the
                                 end of the run.
-i, --interactive                Download and patch formula, then open a
                                 shell. This allows the user to run
                                 ./configure --help and otherwise
                                 determine how to turn the software package
                                 into a Homebrew package.
-g, --git                        Create a Git repository, useful for
                                 creating patches to the software.
-h, --help                       Show this message.
```

Error: invalid option: --with-passenger

This is supposed to work... so yeah.

Comment: I have the same issue. Hope anyone can provide the help.

Answer (score 4):

A late answer. Obviously the documentation on the passenger site is outdated at time of this writing.

According to phusion's github site

https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2187#issue-416881033

the config option **--nginx-with-passenger** is **not valid** anymore.

Instead do:

**brew install nginx passenger**

Addendum:

When using google search for results currently the old page comes up at the top of the list. Here's the currently maintained page with the accurate information:

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/advanced_guides/install_and_upgrade/nginx/install/oss/osx.html

Comment: Maybe updating the old pages with a (hard to miss) banner saying something like "view newer version of this doc" at the top could help many people.